# Querying SQL Server Database Results in "Invalid Object name" error, when it is definitely valid

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# app that hits a couple of different databases to do some analysis. However, for some strange reason, I keep getting an "Invalid object name" error with one of my queries, when I know for a fact that the object exists and is being called properly. This is the query in question (Excuse the one line... it's generated dynamically)

```
;with bqs as ( select data_set_date ,'LSRON' as 'laser_state' ,'control_mode'= case when cntrl_mode='service' then 'PADDLE1' when cntrl_mode='Exposure' then 'SCANNER' end ,null as gas_status ,'shutter_status' = case when cntrl_mode='Exposure' then 'OPEN' when cntrl_mode='service' then 'CLOSED' end ,'BQ' as Event from [FDS_RAM_MTBE].[dbo].[Fault_summ] where serial_number = '61040' and data_set_date > '6/21/2010 12:00:00 AM' and data_set_date < '6/28/2010 12:00:00 AM'), st as(SELECT serial_number ,data_set_date ,S_1 as laser_state ,S_2 as control_mode ,'gas_status' = case when s_28 in ('OPEN','CLOSED','UNKNOWN')then s_27 when s_37 in ('OPEN','CLOSED','UNKNOWN')then s_36 when s_36 like '%TW%' OR s_36 like '%1W%' OR S_39 IN ('0','1','2') then s_38 when s_437 in ('OPEN','CLOSED','UNKNOWN','0','1','2')then s_436 else null end ,'shutter_state'= case when s_28 in ('OPEN','CLOSED','UNKNOWN')then s_28 when s_37 in ('OPEN','CLOSED','UNKNOWN')then s_37 when s_36 like '%TW%' OR s_36 like '%1W%' OR S_39 IN ('0','1','2')then cast(s_39 AS varchar) when s_437 in ('OPEN','CLOSED','UNKNOWN','0','1','2')then s_437 else null end , s_45 as Event FROM CSDFDS2.FDS.DW.FDS_statuses_trx_fvw where serial_number = '61040' and data_set_date > '6/21/2010 12:00:00 AM' and data_set_date < '6/28/2010 12:00:00 AM'), st1 as ( select data_set_date ,Laser_state ,'control_mode'=case when control_mode= 'STEPPER' then 'SCANNER' else control_mode end ,gas_status ,'shutter_status'= case when shutter_state like '1%' then 'OPEN' when shutter_state like '2%' then 'CLOSED' when shutter_state like '0%' then 'UNKNOWN' else shutter_state end ,Event from st) ,un1 as (select * from st1 union select * from bqs)select *from un1 order by data_set_date desc;
```

The error in question is this:

```
Invalid object name 'FDS_RAM_MTBE.dbo.Fault_summ'.
Stack Trace  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)

  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)

  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)

  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)

  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)

  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
  at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
  at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)

  at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
  at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)

  at RAM_UPTIME.DatabaseHandler.executeDataset(String queryString, String tableName) in C:\Documents and Settings\L502570\Desktop\RAM UPTIME\Data Classes\DatabaseHandler.cs:line 216
```

But catch this... If I run:

```
SELECT * from FDS_RAM_MTBE.dbo.Fault_summ 
WHERE serial_number = '61872'
```

It works fine. Pulls the data properly. What in the world is going on?

---

Here is a more formatted version of that query although with variables still left in..

```
;with bqs as (
 select
 data_set_date
 ,'LSRON' as 'laser_state'
 ,'control_mode'= case
 when cntrl_mode='service' then 'PADDLE1'
 when cntrl_mode='Exposure' then 'SCANNER' end
 ,null as gas_status
 ,'shutter_status' = case
 when cntrl_mode='Exposure' then 'OPEN'
 when cntrl_mode='service' then 'CLOSED' end
 ,'BQ' as Event
 from [FDS_RAM_MTBE].[dbo].[Fault_summ]
 where serial_number = ' + laserSerialNo' and data_set_date > ' + startDate' and data_set_date < ' + endDate')

, st as(SELECT
 serial_number
 ,data_set_date
 ,S_1 as laser_state
 ,S_2 as control_mode
 ,'gas_status' = case
 when s_28 in ('OPEN','CLOSED','UNKNOWN')then s_27
 when s_37 in ('OPEN','CLOSED','UNKNOWN')then s_36
 when s_36 like '%TW%' OR s_36 like '%1W%' OR S_39 IN ('0','1','2') then s_38
 when s_437 in ('OPEN','CLOSED','UNKNOWN','0','1','2')then s_436 else null end
 ,'shutter_state'= case
 when s_28 in ('OPEN','CLOSED','UNKNOWN')then s_28
 when s_37 in ('OPEN','CLOSED','UNKNOWN')then s_37
 when s_36 like '%TW%' OR s_36 like '%1W%' OR S_39 IN ('0','1','2')then cast(s_39 AS varchar)
 when s_437 in ('OPEN','CLOSED','UNKNOWN','0','1','2')then s_437 else null end
 , s_45 as Event
 FROM CSDFDS2.FDS.DW.FDS_statuses_trx_fvw
 where serial_number = ' + laserSerialNo' and data_set_date > ' + startDate' and data_set_date < ' + endDate')

, st1 as (
 select
 data_set_date
 ,Laser_state
 ,'control_mode'=case
 when control_mode= 'STEPPER' then 'SCANNER' else control_mode end
 ,gas_status
 ,'shutter_status'= case
 when shutter_state like '1%' then 'OPEN'
 when shutter_state like '2%' then 'CLOSED'
 when shutter_state like '0%' then 'UNKNOWN' else shutter_state end
 ,Event
 from st
) ,un1 as (select * from st1 union select * from bqs)
select *
from un1 order by data_set_date desc;
```

Comment: Divide et impera, Test each CTE separately

Comment: They work separately, which is the really annoying part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you append CSDFDS2 to the first CTE?

```
FROM [CSDFDS2].[FDS_RAM_MTBE].[dbo].[Fault_summ]
```

Comment: It's actually from a different linked server. And yes, I tried appending that server's name too... Same error. Actually, the script is being run on the server for which the table can't be found... Weird that it can find the external table and not the local one.

Comment: Maybe the connection is being made in the context of the linked server, but then you would have to check if the local server is 'linked' in the linked server

Comment: Hmm... I'll try that. Unfortunately I'm going to have to go through IT to get write permissions on that server.

Comment: Well... but you can check first the context of the connection.

Comment: The connection is definitely to the local server (not CSDFDS2). It's made with a trusted connection login, so I figure it kind of has to be.

Comment: Turns out you were right. The context was being changed to the remote server for no good damn reason. Stupid old code no one has touched in years...

Answer (score 0):

You sure you are connected to the database you think you are?

You sure this isn't an error from an underlying view which has become invalid?

Comment: Yes and reasonably. Fault_summ is indeed a view, but if I query it with a simple Select * from [FDS_RAM_MTBE].[dbo].[Fault_summ] everything gets returned just fine.